# Affecting multiple classes on :active

Tags: html, css, text, css-selectors

I'm working on an HTML project and i added a checkbox, which when checked would highlite all text input fields. The only problem is that some of the input fields are inside tables and for some reason i can't affect them with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ShowAll" id="mut" />

<!--Tätigkeit-->
        <input type="text" class="tt" id="BT" />
        <input type="text" class="tt" id="MA" />

        <table id="tatigkeit">
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tBT" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tEB" /></td><td><input type="text" class="tt" id="tTT" /></td></tr>
        </table>

        <!--Anlieferungen + Geratschaften + Besondere Vorkommnisse-->
        <input type="text" class="tt" id="ANL" />
        <input type="text" class="tt" id="GER" />
```

CSS:

```
#mut:checked ~.tt
{
    background: #ffffaa;
}
```

I've tried in many different ways, but it's always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). As the name implies it selects succeeding sibling elements. Since the input elements inside of the table are *not* siblings, you need to select the table element and then select the input elements from there:

```
#mut:checked ~ .tt,
#mut:checked ~ table input {
    background: #ffffaa;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nafkpzwj/)

As a side note, if you only want to select text input elements, use the attribute selector `[type="text"]`:

```
#mut:checked ~ table input[type="text"] {}
```

Comment: Yeah to be honest, what i tried was `#mut:checked ~input, ~table input` but yeah, thank a lot!